# Create new sheets for each site searched and paste its infos in each new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, search

i'm quite new with vba macros, but i'm trying to code a macro with vba where i can search specific site and copy the entire page in for each new sheet created for each site searched. I tryed to copy the especific table, but i realized that the position for the specific table differes from each site, so i just want to copy the entire page from each searched site and then, create new sheets and paste it. So i can use some filter or something. But i'm not succeeding on cerate news sheet for each site. I would be happy if someone could help me.

```
Private Sub Table()

    Dim a1 As String
    Dim a2 As String
    Dim a3 As String
    Dim a4 As String
    
    a1 = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruzeiro_do_Sul_(Acre)"
    a2 = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitaciolândia"
    a3 = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feijó"
    a4 = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marechal_Thaumaturgo"

    Dim table1 As QueryTable
    Dim table2 As QueryTable
    Dim table3 As QueryTable
    Dim table4 As QueryTable

    
    Set table1 = shResult.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & a1, shResult.Range("A1"))
    Set table2 = shResult.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & a2, shResult.Range("A15"))
    Set table3 = shResult.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & a3, shResult.Range("A30"))
    Set table4 = shResult.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & a4, shResult.Range("A45"))
     
        With table1
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
            .Refresh
        End With
        With table2
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
            .Refresh
        End With
        With table3
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
            .Refresh
        End With
        With table4
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
            .Refresh
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this can help you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetClimateDataEN(www As String)

    Dim shResult As Worksheet
    Dim table As QueryTable
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range

    On Error GoTo Err

    With Excel.Application
    
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    
        With .ThisWorkbook
            Set shResult = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
            Set table = shResult.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & www, Destination:=shResult.Range("A1"))
        End With
    
        With table
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    
        'Set the first cell of the table (cell value "Climate data for")
        Set rng = .ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Climate data for", After:=.ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        'Set last cell in the first column of the table (cell value "Mean monthly sunshine hours")
        Set rng1 = .ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Mean monthly sunshine hours", After:=.ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        'Set and copy the table range
        Set rng = .Range(rng, rng1)
        .Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)).Copy
        'Paste it on worksheet_1
        With .Worksheets(1)
            .Range("A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With
        'Delete the QueryTable worksheet
        .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
    
        .Worksheets(1).Activate
    
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End With
    Exit Sub

Err:
    'VBA.MsgBox "An error has occurred"

End Sub
```

You can call this procedure from your macros with this line:

```
Call GetClimateDataEN("Your URL here")
```

This works if the language of the web page is English, otherwise you need to adjust the code. Read the comments in the code to understand what it does.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sir, it did works great!!! But every time that a link has no temperature table, it gives the error message. Is there any way to avoid it so i dont need to press enter every time?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now you will now no longer receive an error message.

Glad to have been helpful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could start from something like this (I just added a couple of lines to your code):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Table()

    Dim a1 As String
    Dim a2 As String
    Dim a3 As String
    Dim a4 As String
    Dim shResult As Worksheet
    
    a1 = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruzeiro_do_Sul_(Acre)"
    a2 = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitaciolândia"
    a3 = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feijó"
    a4 = "https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marechal_Thaumaturgo"

    Dim table1 As QueryTable
    Dim table2 As QueryTable
    Dim table3 As QueryTable
    Dim table4 As QueryTable

    Set shResult = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set table1 = shResult.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & a1, shResult.Range("A1"))
    Set shResult = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set table2 = shResult.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & a2, shResult.Range("A15"))
    Set shResult = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set table3 = shResult.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & a3, shResult.Range("A30"))
    Set shResult = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set table4 = shResult.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & a4, shResult.Range("A45"))
     
    With table1
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
        .Refresh
    End With
    With table2
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
        .Refresh
    End With
    With table3
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
        .Refresh
    End With
    With table4
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
        .Refresh
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now i need to filter a certain table of info from each page pasted, do you know how can i do it?

Comment: Read here:  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)  What is the table you are interested in filtering from each page?

Comment: Temperature from each city in the wikipedia link, like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Paulo